# Can't adjust sidebar height

Tags: css

I am using Bootstrap. Sidebar row height is equal to. Idont want this

[image: img]

```css
html, body {
  height           : 100%;
  overflow-x       : hidden;
  background-color : #F6F8FC;
  }
.sidebar {
  display          : flex;
  flex-direction   : column;
  height           : 100%;
  background-color : #171829;
  box-shadow       : 0 0 21px 0 rgb(89 102 122 / 10%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0;"> 
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo">
      <span>Admin Panel</span>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      <ul>
        <li>Gösterge Paneli</li>
        <li>Yazılar</li>
        <li>Sayfalar</li>
        <li>Kategoriler</li>
        <li>Kullanıcılar</li>
        <li>Site Ayarları`</li>
      </ul>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

I want to set the sidebar height to 100%.

Comment: please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)....   `I am using Bootstrap` are you expecting that every body can know whitch version you use ? there is also no tag for bootstrap ?

Comment: Just to be sure... Are you cleaning the browser cache after every try?

Comment: One more question: is the parent of the `sidebar` with the height at 100%? Which HTML element is the parent? Check the hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry, my English is very bad. I am using Bootstrap 5. sidebar height 100%

Answer (score 0):

instead height: "100%" use min-height: "100vh"

`.sidebar { min-height: "100vh" }`

Comment: I tried but the room doesn't work. I can't figure it out

Comment: are you trying:  html, body {min-height: "100vh"}

Comment: yes i tried both